# CSS Using div to simulate tables

Tags: html, css

I'm new as webdesigner and I have to create a portion of a page that has 3 columns: a menu on the left side, the central body and a vertical banner. I can't use tables, so I've created a similar HTML:

```
<div class="Body">
   <div class="LeftMenu">My menu</div>
   <div class="Content">Foo body</div>
   <div class="VerticalBanner">My menu</div>
</div>
```

While the CSS:

```
.LeftMenu {
width: 20%;
}
.Content {
margin: auto;
left: 20%;
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
width: 60%;
}
.VerticalBanner {
left: 80%;
margin: auto;
position: absolute;
top: 0%;
width: 20%;
}
```

So, my problem using that code is that the parent div (Body) takes the height of the first div (LeftMenu), which is not the bigger. This causes the content of "Content" and "VerticalBanner" to flow out "Body" and to go under the Footer div. If I use the float attribute, the "Body" div collapse without dimensions and then the footer div slides under the three columns inside "Body".

I also tried with display attribute, but Internet Explorer doesn't support this and some columns have strange behaviour.

What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: There is a nice [float tutorial here](http://css.maxdesign.com.au/floatutorial/), lesson 9 sounds very much like your case. maybe you could check it?

Comment: have a look [Here](http://www.cssplay.co.uk/layouts/three-column-layouts.html) and [Here](http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/perfect-3-column.htm).
There are nice guides on how to realize pure CSS cross-browser 3 columns layouts

Comment: Just to clarify, you're not using DIV instead of TABLE, because you should never think about using TABLE this way. The meaning of TABLE does not compete with aligning portions of a site side by side. This is a division of the layout, ie, the meaning of DIV. When we think semantically since the beginning, we avoid this type of "incorrect" comparison. Just to help you with the concepts since you're already starting...

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use floats for your DIVs. It's much easier after that to move them around.

Answer (score 0):

Use `display: table-*`:

```
.Body { display: table; }
.Left, .Content, .VerticalBanner { display: table-cell; }
```

See e.g. [this JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/urdh/DD6Ae/2/).

Answer (score 0):

To stop the body div from collapsing you can use

```
.body{ overflow: hidden; }
```

I'm don't think you need position absolute.

Answer (score -1):

```
<div class="Body">
   <div style="width:20%;float:left;">My menu</div>
   <div style="width:60%;float:left;">Foo body</div>
   <div style="width:20%;float:left;">My menu</div>
   <div style="height:1px;font-size:1px;clear:both;">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

Comment: -1 for clearing `div`. Those have been [unnecessary for a long time](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html).

Comment: oh ... +1 for link then ... is much cleaner!

Comment: I was also thinking about clearing. Thanks for the link @You.